# PowerShell: Runspace problem with DownloadFileAsync

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I needed to download file using `WebClient` in PowerShell 2.0, and I wanted to show download progress, so I did it this way:

```
$activity = "Downloading"

$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$urlAsUri = New-Object System.Uri($url)

$event = New-Object System.Threading.ManualResetEvent($false)

$downloadProgress = [System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler] {
    $progress = [int]((100.0 * $_.BytesReceived) / $_.TotalBytesToReceive)
    Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status "${progress}% done" -PercentComplete $progress
}

$downloadComplete = [System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler] {
    Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Completed
    $event.Set()
}

$client.add_DownloadFileCompleted($downloadComplete) 
$client.add_DownloadProgressChanged($downloadProgress)

Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status "0% done" -PercentComplete 0
$client.DownloadFileAsync($urlAsUri, $file)    

$event.WaitOne()
```

I am getting a error `There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread.` for the code in `$downloadProgress` handler, which is logical. However, how do I provide a `Runspace` for the thread that (probably) belongs to the `ThreadPool`?

**UPDATE:**
Note that *both* answers to this question are worth reading, and I would accept both if I could.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks stej for the nod.

Andrey, powershell has its own threadpool and each service thread keeps a threadstatic pointer to a runspace (the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace static member exposes this - and would be a null ref in your callbacks.) Ultimately this means it's difficult - especially in script - to use your own threadpool (as is provided by .NET for async methods) to execute scriptblocks.

**PowerShell 2.0**

Regardless, there is no need to play with this as powershell v2 has full support for eventing:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = [uri]"http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/F/" +
    "62F70029-A592-4158-BB51-E102812CBD4F/IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe"

try {

   Register-ObjectEvent $client DownloadProgressChanged -action {     

        Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading" -Status `
            ("{0} of {1}" -f $eventargs.BytesReceived, $eventargs.TotalBytesToReceive) `
            -PercentComplete $eventargs.ProgressPercentage    
    }

    Register-ObjectEvent $client DownloadFileCompleted -SourceIdentifier Finished

    $file = "c:\temp\ie9-beta.exe"
    $client.DownloadFileAsync($url, $file)

    # optionally wait, but you can break out and it will still write progress
    Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier Finished

} finally { 
    $client.dispose()
}
```

**PowerShell v1.0**

If you're stuck on v1 (this is not specifically for you as you mention v2 in the question) you can use my powershell 1.0 eventing snap-in at http://pseventing.codeplex.com/

**Async Callbacks**

Another tricky area in .NET is async callbacks. There is nothing directly in v1 or v2 of powershell that can help you here, but you can convert an async callback to an event with some simple plumbing and then deal with that event using regular eventing. I posted a script for this (New-ScriptBlockCallback) at http://poshcode.org/1382

Hope this helps,

-Oisin

Comment: Yes, the `New-ScriptBlockCallback` was exactly what I had on mind when I mentioned you would have an answer :)

Comment: cool, now I returned to the question and I have absolutely no idea what answer to accept :)

Comment: hey there is an `Add-Type` method! and here I was trying to emit IL needed to set Runspace.

Comment: Yeah, my pseventing v1 snapin is full of reflection.emit goodness.

Comment: Link is broken but exists in wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160404214529/http://poshcode.org/1382. Or take it from x0n's blog post: http://www.nivot.org/post/2009/10/09/PowerShell20AsynchronousCallbacksFromNET. Or from Github, well you get the picture: https://github.com/PowerShell/Polaris/blob/master/Public/New-ScriptblockCallback.ps1

Answer (score 6):

I see that you use async call so that you can show the progress. Then you can use BitsTransfer module for that. It shows the progress by default:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -dest d:\temp\yourfile.zip
```

If you would like to transfer the file in the background, you could use something like this:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer

$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 300
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
    if ($transfer.JobState -ne 'Transferring') { 
        $timer.Enabled = 0; 
        Write-Progress -Completed -Activity Downloading -Status done
        return 
    }
    $progress = [int](100* $transfer.BytesTransferred/$transfer.BytesTotal)
    Write-Progress -Activity Downloading -Status "$progress% done" -PercentComplete $progress
} -sourceId mytransfer
$transfer = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -dest d:\temp\yourfile.zip -async
$timer.Enabled = 1

# after that
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier mytransfer
$timer.Dispose()
```

The key parameter is `-async`. It starts the transfer in background. I haven't found any event triggered by the transfer, so I query the job each second to report the state via `Timers.Timer` object.

However with this solution, it is needed to unregister the event and dispose the timer. Some time ago I had problems with unregistering in the scriptblock passed as `-Action` (it could be in the `if` branch), so I unregister the event in separate command.

---

I think @oising (x0n) has some solution on his blog. He'll tell you that hopefully and that would be answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is pure genius. Much better than my solution. Now I will wait a bit to see if anyone answer the Runspace part before accepting (just curious what's the deal with it).

Comment: I'll another option just for inspiration :)

Comment: @stej - you can unregister from within a handler with "unregister-event -subscriberid $eventsubscription.subscriberid"

Comment: I tried to avoid calling `Unregister-event` from the handler because some time ago https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/541360/posh-console-hangs-when-unregistering-event#details . But today, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: that's very cool. I was torn on which answer to accept, but the other one is more directly related to the title/text of my question and will probably be more useful for Googlers. Though I would accept both if I could.

Comment: Sure, that's why I let x0n know about this question.

Comment: @stej - I'll just vote up your next few answers even if I think you're on crack! :D

Comment: @x0n I hope you are still voting up :D