# Is there any way to run multiple instances of a single power shell script with different arguments at same time

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I have multiple folders, each containing many images. I am using ImageMagick's compare.exe to compare each image with verified images. I wrote script to traverse each folder one by one and pass it to another script which traverse each image in that folder and compare.exe executable compare each image after that it passes another folder and same process repeats. So the problem is that my main script runs in sequential mode like script picks one folder, then another and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell v2.0 Using multiple threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178003/powershell-v2-0-using-multiple-threads)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)