# Unexpected error occurred running a simple unauthorized Rest query

Tags: rest, powershell

I have a rest endpoint that doesn't perform an authentication check. I can run a simple curl commmand from Linux:

```
curl -k https://application/api/about
```

This responds.

However if try the following on PowerShell it fails:

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://application/api/about
```

Then I get:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod $Application
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Could some one please tell me how I can get around this problem ?

**EDIT:**

Trying with Invoke-WebRequest:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://application/api/about"
```

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send. At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://application/api/a ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Could you just use Invoke-WebRequest instead?

Comment: I wish I could... Same error (I'll post result in Edit)

Comment: I see you're using https, do you have certs setup correctly? Try running this first, "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}", then try the Invoke-webRequest again

Answer (score 92):

Using:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Taken from 
[Powershell 3.0 Invoke-WebRequest HTTPS Fails on All Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143946/powershell-3-0-invoke-webrequest-https-fails-on-all-requests/25163476#25163476).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed

Comment: This is gold! Worked like a charm.

Comment: unbelievable 15K views... 48 up votes. thanks for the info.

Comment: How did you know to set this value?  I just want to know how we were all supposed to figure this out

Comment: @aaaaaa - we figured it out by searching StackOverflow :) and found this answer

Comment: This setting is to be done during each PowerShell session. It works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: If you get a 'not recognized' error, I used `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls12'` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 23):

In my case the TLS trick was not the problem. It was due to certificate mismatch. Although you can use {$true} for the callback, this does not scale well. Eventually powershell will fail with an error indicated it failed to load a runspace. This seems to be a bug in powershell. Instead, you need to add the callback **using .net code instead of a scriptblock**.

```
#C# class to create callback
$code = @"
public class SSLHandler
{
    public static System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback GetSSLHandler()
    {

        return new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });
    }
    
}
"@

#compile the class
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code

#disable checks using new class
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = [SSLHandler]::GetSSLHandler()
#do the request
try
{
    invoke-WebRequest -Uri myurl -UseBasicParsing
} catch {
    # do something
} finally {
   #enable checks again
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null
}
```

Comment: This worked for me while setting `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` and `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy` didn't.

Comment: @justin I do not understand why this worked, but it did.  Is it a powershell version issue?

Comment: @AndyArismendi using {$true} does work, but you can get yourself into trouble if there are too many calls to https. that is why you need a compiled class.

Comment: @MonaLisaOverdrive as far as i can tell it is a powershell issue, basically it keeps reloading the powershell runspace and eventually reaches a point where it can't.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Works in Windows server 2016

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      17763  1007